# How can a page tell if it is being served on local LAN?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip-address, lan

My project is a web-application that is to serve as a company Landing Page with a logo and quick links.

I would like to add extra links to LAN-based webpages for users who are in my local LAN, but hide those links if the page is served outside the local LAN.

I know how to hide and show things
How can I tell whether the page is served in the LAN or outside the LAN?

This is the only thing I've come up with so far, but I'm not sure it will work.  (strings.left() is one of my own function that fetches the first x characters from the left of a string)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    String thisipaddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];

    if (thisipaddress == "127.0.0.1" || strings.left(thisipaddress,7)=="192.168"){
        hiddenarea.Visible = true;
    } else {
        hiddenarea.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

I guess what I need to know is, with my current code, if a user in another LAN access my page, will my code detect their internal ipaddress or their external one?

Comment: It is generally considered a security risk if you allow external internet access to an intranet. Is that the case here?

Comment: What you need is some several network working here with your own DNS. Not For SO, instead stack fault

Comment: The page is public facing.  I want to add links to internal pages, too - but only that they show for internal users.  I'm not making an internal page to have external access.  And I'm posting here in Stack Overflow because I want to do this in C#.
I just want to detect whether the page is being served inside the LAN or outside.

Comment: Would this work? `bool isLocal = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal;`

Comment: @bgmCoder [`IsLocal` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.islocal?view=netframework-4.8): "The IsLocal property returns true if the IP address of the request originator is 127.0.0.1 or if the IP address of the request is the same as the server's IP address."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick.  It detects external ip address from outside the lan and internal ipaddress from inside the lan.  And if the page is accessed from an external LAN with a matching ipaddress, it still returns the external one.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
String thisipaddress = Request.UserHostAddress;   <-----THIS

if (thisipaddress == "127.0.0.1" || strings.left(thisipaddress,7)=="192.168"){
    hiddenarea.Visible = true;
} else {
    hiddenarea.Visible = false;
}
```

}

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress#System_Web_HttpRequest_UserHostAddress

Comment: Figures!  I always solve my own questions right after I post them.  I can spend hours trying to solve it, but when I post, then I solve!